# Select Cursor(caret) Right and Left side character or word in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to select a character where it is placed right and left side of Cursor.But I Could not do it.

I'm doing this because I want to check there is any character present at right and left side of cursor

position.I'm using the below code to select the text in a cursor position.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
sel = editor.getSelection();
sel.selectElement(sel.getStartElement());
```

But i want something more From this.How can i do this.

**OR**

There is any way to getting next value from cursor position And also Getting Previous value From

the Cursor Position in CKEditor.